# What algorithm does MsOffice use for file encryption?

Tags: ms-office, file-format

I am looking for documentation on the encryption algorithm used by Office for its BIFF files.

The documetation says:
"All records after FILEPASS are encrypted (see the Office Open XML specification (Ecma Internation Standard 376) for further details)."

I looked at the ECMA documentation but could not find anything related to encryption for BIFF.

Any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Probably RC4, or something else called SEAL:
http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf (page 169)